# Is partial application of higher order functions possible in C?

Tags: c, higher-order-functions, partial-application

Let's say I have a function

```
int myfun (int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
    /* function body */
}
```

and I would like to write a function `pass_last_elements()` that has signature

```
int (*)(int, int) pass_last_elements(int (*myfun)(int, int, int, int), int x3, int x4);
```

and returns a function of two arguments, let's call it `fun_out`, such that `fun_out(x1, x2)` computes the same result as `myfun(x1, x2, x3, x4)`.

Is it possible to do this purely in C? If not, would it be possible to do it using some compiler extensions?

Comment: Declaring higher order functions in C is easier if you use typedefs.

Comment: You're asking whether C has closures. The answer is no.

Comment: Easy enough in C++, but in C? I don't think so.

Comment: In C, could instead return a `struct`  with members `int (*foo)(state *, int, int)` and `state bar` and late call `x.foo(&x.bar, x1,x2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the function signature, you put the function identifier "inside":

```
int (* pass_last_elements(int (*myfun)(int, int, int, int), int x3, int x4) )(int, int);
```

As to:

> returns a function of two arguments, let's call it fun_out, such that fun_out(x1, x2) computes the same result as myfun(x1, x2, x3, x4)

C language does not have closures nor lambdas etc., so it's not possible. You have to pass context (i.e. the state of variables `x1` and `x2`) yourself, either by adding a context argument to the function (like `cookie` in `fopencookie` or `arg` in `qsort_r`) or using global variables,